# How to confirm if diode bridge is faulty

Tags: diodes, bridge-rectifier

[image: Circuit with diode bridge]

How could I confirm if the faulty component in my circuit is the diode bridge (marked as B) in the attached image?

If I set my polimeter to AC and measure LN in point A I get the correct 220v, but there is no voltage between the diode AC inputs, so this makes me think that maybe some other component is faulty.

Any ideas on how to confirm the faulty component in the attached image circuit?

Comment: Do you have the schematic?

Comment: To check the 4 diodes of the bridge with the multimeter, I would desolder the bridge from the board. Each diode should be checked for both directions of current.

Comment: Sorry no schematics, as it's a board I'm trying to fix. Just want to find the faulty component before manipulation. The circuit seems quite simple to me, but I have no idea a about the voltages I should get at each stage

Comment: Diode bridges usually fail either shorted or visibly burned open.  If you check the  resistance between the DC terminals in circuit, you should get resistance in one direction and practically zero in the other direction. You should have done that before applying power. Since you have no voltage across the AC terminals, check the bridge in circuit with the power removed. Next trace between the AC bridge terminals and the power input to the board an see what is open.